# Wrong time on Docker debian container despite NTP

Tags: docker, ntp

I am creating a simple debian-based docker (`php:7-apache`). To create it I use:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name myname -v "$PWD":/var/www/html php:7-apache
```

I noticed that my docker is possibly suffering from [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/time-in-container-is-out-of-sync/16566/6) issue, therefore now, each time I run the container, I also run:

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host php:7-apache nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i date -u $(date -u +%m%d%H%M%Y)
```

This fixed my issue. The clock is now ok. However, before trying this, I simply tried to install ntp on the docker and set it up:

```
# apt-get install ntp
# vi /etc/ntp.conf # commented pools and added these servers http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/europe
# /etc/init.d/ntp start
# /usr/bin/ntpq -p    
remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
v.bsod.fr       193.190.230.66   2 u   24   64    1   32.924  -117284   0.004
tomia.ordimatic 62.210.36.58     3 u   23   64    1   26.158  -117286   0.004
pacifica.ufp.ne 162.23.41.10     2 u   25   64    1   27.922  -117281   0.004
aquila.init7.ne 189.247.1.117    2 u   24   64    1   34.736  -117291   0.004

# date
...WRONG DATE!!!
```

So, why isn't ntp working? 
I would assume it's better to get NTP to work so that if drifts occur they are correct automatically, instead of setting by hand once the clock from my host system.

Thanks

**EDIT: Second Try**

```
apt-get install ntp 

# setting time
sed 's/pool /#pool /g' /etc/ntp.conf > /tmp/ntp.conf.tmp
echo "server 0.europe.pool.ntp.org" >> /tmp/ntp.conf.tmp
echo "server 1.europe.pool.ntp.org" >> /tmp/ntp.conf.tmp
echo "server 2.europe.pool.ntp.org" >> /tmp/ntp.conf.tmp
echo "server 3.europe.pool.ntp.org" >> /tmp/ntp.conf.tmp
mv /tmp/ntp.conf.tmp /etc/ntp.conf
ntpd -qxg | grep "ntpd:"
/etc/init.d/ntp start
echo "Date on ws container: `date` - correct: `(curl time.correct.com?iso)2>/dev/null`"
```

Gives me:

```
13 Apr 11:40:47 ntpd[922]: ntpd: time slew +14.502687 s
ntpd: time slew +14.502687s
[ ok ] Starting NTP server: ntpd.
Date on ws container: Fri Apr 13 11:40:47 UTC 2018 - correct: 2018-04-13T11:41:02Z
```

So, despite trying to set the time manually with ntpd (ntpdate is deprecated as per http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.0/ntpd.htm), and do getting that I'm 14 seconds behind, the container doesn't get the time set. Any idea on my mistake?
The script above is run with a `docker exec` (with or without --privilege doesn't make a difference).

The full output of `ntpd -qxg` is as follows:

```
13 Apr 12:52:43 ntpd[922]: ntpd 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Sun Feb 25 21:22:55 UTC 2018 (1): Starting
13 Apr 12:52:43 ntpd[922]: Command line: ntpd -qxg
13 Apr 12:52:43 ntpd[922]: proto: precision = 3.398 usec (-18)
13 Apr 12:52:43 ntpd[922]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
13 Apr 12:52:43 ntpd[922]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
13 Apr 12:52:43 ntpd[922]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1:123
13 Apr 12:52:43 ntpd[922]: Listen normally on 3 eth0 172.17.0.3:123
13 Apr 12:52:43 ntpd[922]: Listening on routing socket on fd #21 for interface updates
13 Apr 12:52:50 ntpd[922]: ntpd: time slew -2.923397 s
ntpd: time slew -2.923397s
```

**EDIT2: Found solution!**

Solution follows. The answer by @kubanczyk is correct, but in the specifics of Docker we need to super-power the manual time update:

```
# apt-get install ntp
# nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i ntpd -qxg
# /etc/init.d/ntp start
```

Comment: In general: Simply starting an ntp service will not *immediately* synchronise to the correct time - it starts a process to **gradually shift** (slew) the clock to the correct time which will be slow when the offset between the internal clock and the external NTP servers is large and fails completely when that offset is too large (>1000 seconds). Tune that behaviour with the for instance the `-x` and `-g` [ntpd options](http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.0/ntpd.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ntpq` offset is in milliseconds, for example `offset -117291` translates to about 117 seconds difference.

The UDP connectivity is correct. If it wasn't, you wouldn't get an offset.

The `ntpd` conservatively refuses to set the clock. Generally, it only works by slowing/speeding the clock slightly. (And when the time offset is larger than 1000 seconds, it ignores the source completely).

You need to stop `ntpd` and run `ntpdate` to set your clock. Now start `ntpd` back up. The offset would be smaller, so it will synchronize much faster. The time is precisely synchronized when `ntpq` displays a `*` like this:

```
# ntpq -pn
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*10.0.21.44      10.0.21.1        6 u  370 1024  377    1.570   -0.926   6.177
+10.0.21.46      10.0.21.1        6 u  246 1024  377    2.616    2.904   6.750
-10.0.21.45      192.168.1.1      6 u  391 1024  377    1.620   13.230   9.495
+10.0.21.47      192.168.1.1      6 u  327 1024  377    2.463    2.994  11.56
-10.0.192.50     10.0.21.44       7 u  213 1024  377    0.357   -5.926  11.969
```

Comment: If you start `ntpd` with `-g` or `-G`, you don't need to run `ntpdate`.  This is the default on many distributions, so the comment that `ntpd` refuses to set the clock is not true in those cases.